# How to optimize SQL query for funnel analysis?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, window-functions, amazon-athena

I am trying to do a funnel analysis where I want to observe how many users reached from start event to end event. Let's say I want to analyze funnel made of 3 events i.e. Visit, Sign Up and Activate.

I have a table where all the user events are stored with columns like user_id, epoch_utc, event_date, event_name and the medium through which the user event came in the system. I need to show the users who completed the funnel (events in the given order) and break them up by which users dropped at which event and their count wrt to medium.

I have written the query as discussed in this link -

https://popsql.com/sql-templates/marketing/running-a-funnel-analysis

The query is as follows:

```
with visit_users as (
    select user_id, min(epoch_utc) as min_time, min(medium) as medium, count(event_name) as total_events from events_table 
    where  date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_parse('2022-09-16','%Y-%m-%d') and date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_parse('2022-09-22','%Y-%m-%d')
    and event_name = 'Visit'
    group by 1
),

signup_users as (
    select su.user_id, su.min_time, su.medium, su.total_events from 
    (
        select user_id, min(epoch_utc) as min_time, min(medium) as medium, count(event_name) as total_events from (
            SELECT user_id, epoch_utc, medium, event_name   FROM events_table 
                where  date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_parse('2022-09-16','%Y-%m-%d') and date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_parse('2022-09-22','%Y-%m-%d')  AND 
                ( event_name = 'Sign Up' ) 
        ) group by 1
    ) su, visit_users acu
    where su.user_id = acu.user_id
    and su.min_time > acu.min_time
),

activate_users as (
    select icu.user_id, icu.min_time, icu.medium, icu.total_events from 
    (
        select user_id, min(epoch_utc) as min_time, min(medium) as medium, count(event_name) as total_events from (
            SELECT user_id, epoch_utc, medium, event_name   FROM events_table 
                where  date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_parse('2022-09-16','%Y-%m-%d') and date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_parse('2022-09-22','%Y-%m-%d')  AND 
                ( event_name = 'Activate' ) 
        ) group by 1
    ) icu, signup_users su
    where icu.user_id = su.user_id
    and icu.min_time > su.min_time
)

select * from (
    select step, medium, count(user_id) as total_users, 0 as total_time, 0 as avg_time, sum(total_events) as total_events from (
    select 'Visit' as step, acu.medium, acu.user_id, 
    0, acu.total_events from visit_users acu
    ) group by 1, 2 
    UNION
    select step, medium, count(user_id) as total_users, sum(diff) as total_time, (sum(diff) / count(user_id) ) as avg_time, sum(total_events) as total_events from ( 
    select 'Sign Up' as step, su.medium, su.user_id, 
    date_diff('second', from_unixtime(acu.min_time/1000) , from_unixtime(su.min_time/1000)) as diff,
    su.total_events
    from visit_users acu, signup_users su
    where acu.user_id = su.user_id
    ) group by 1, 2 
    UNION
    select step, medium, count(user_id) as total_users, sum(diff) as total_time, (sum(diff) / count(user_id) ) as avg_time, sum(total_events) as total_events from ( 
    select 'Activate' as step, icu.medium, icu.user_id, 
    date_diff('second', from_unixtime(su.min_time/1000) , from_unixtime(icu.min_time/1000)) as diff,
    icu.total_events
    from signup_users su, activate_users icu
    where su.user_id = icu.user_id
    ) group by 1, 2
) order by step, total_users desc
```

Now the user can define a funnel at runtime and instead of these 3 events, it can be more number of events in a funnel. Is there any way to optimize the above query to work for n events with slight change.

We use java based application to generate the query. Is there any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to improve the performance by creating a CTAS (Create Table as Select) in Athena. events_table was a temp table created using CTE at runtime.

In Athena, the CTAS table content will be stored in S3, so I created a temp CTAS table from events_table by applying below query.

select user_id, epoch_utc, event_name, medium from events_table where  date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_parse('2022-09-16','%Y-%m-%d') and date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_parse('2022-09-22','%Y-%m-%d')
and event_name in ('Visit','Sign Up','Activate')

Then in the query in the question, instead of referring event_table, referred this CTAS table.

The performance improves drastically for huge amount of data.